# Hardhat balanceOf return 0 of forked network address

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I am playing with `hardhat`. My goal is to print `balanceOf` specific address from the forked main network.

hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.0",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: "https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/my-api-key",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}

contract Balance {
    
   function getBalance() public returns (uint) {
     
       address ethAddr = address(0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2); 
       address addrWithBalance = 0x00000000219ab540356cBB839Cbe05303d7705Fa; // <-- address from etherium scan from main net with huge balance

       uint balance = IERC20(ethAddr).balanceOf(addrWithBalance);

       console.log(balance); // <- here print 0, expecting 7,729,794.000069000000000069 ether

       return balance;
    }  
}
```

test:

```
  it("Should print balance", async function () {
    const BalanceContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Balance");
    const balanceToken = await BalanceContract.deploy();
    
    const balance = await balanceToken.getBalance()       

    console.log(balance) 
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `--network localhost` flag.

`yarn hardhat test --network localhost`